# Saving SqlConnection.InfoMessage to string in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sqlconnection

How can i catch `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` and save it into `string`? I couldn't find any examples so i'm asking here.

Sample operation on database:

```
        public async Task AddAsync(Items record)
        {
            using (var context = new DBEntities())
            {
                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                context.Items.Add(record);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

How can i do this on this example?

If i understand correctly it will let me catch `PRINT` messages and this is exactly what i want to do.

Edit

Am i doing this correctly?

```
        public async Task AddAsync(Items record)
        {
            using (var context = new DBEntities())
            {
                var con = (SqlConnection)context.Database.Connection;

                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                context.Items.Add(record);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                con.InfoMessage += (obj, args) =>
                {
                    SQLServerLogHandler.LogDisplay.LogPrint = args.Message;
                };
            }
        }
```

I'm interested only in latest message from the server.`SQLServerLogHandler.LogDisplay.LogPrint` is just static string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF6:

```
var messages = new List<string>();
var con = (SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection;
con.InfoMessage += (s, a) =>
{
    messages.Add(a.Message);
};
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("print 'foo'");
```

EF Core:

```
var messages = new List<string>();
var con = (SqlConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
con.InfoMessage += (s, a) =>
{
    messages.Add(a.Message);
};
db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("print 'foo'");
```

Comment: You need to add the event handler before you'll start seeing the messages.  So move it ahead of SaveChanges if you expect to see any messages generated by SaveChanges.

Comment: Alright, moved it. So far no messages registered because there was no `PRINT` triggered. I hope it will work. Thanks for help, it appears this is the first example on the internet.